# Accessing Shared Folder from Windows Server via Internet

Tags: networking, ftp, windows-server-2012, sftp

Is there any way to share a folder from my remote Windows Server 2012 and access that folder via the Internet from another Windows and Mac machine?

All the machines are not on the same LAN, so I need to access them via the Internet.

I was thinking of FTP/SFTP Server, but I set up FTP server and accessed it through LAN, but I don't know how to make it work via the internet. I am not sure how to set up SFTP either.

Is there any way that I can my goal here? All I was is to share a folder in my Remote Windows machine (which is running Windows Server 2012) and access it from multiple machines (both Windows and Mac) via Internet. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need for your FTP server to be accessible over the Internet.

On your Router/Firewall, you will need to open TCP port 20, 21 and point them Windows 2012 Server. If you have static IP address, then that is all you need to do,  if you have dynamic IP address, then get service from DDNS.

As always, Secure FTP is better option than plain FTP server.

Instruction for AWS:

" Log in to the AWS EC2 Management Console and select Security Groups from the navigation tree on the left. Select the security group assigned to your EC2 instance. Select the Inbound tab and add port range 20-21 "

Source: https://gist.github.com/gunjanpatel/37d306cd1585ece1179b

Comment: My remote machine is AWS EC2 instance. Where do I see router option in AWS instance? Any idea.

Comment: I have updated my answer.